# PHP/MySQL - creating a multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql

This is my piece of code:

```
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $total                = 0; // used for displaying the total price at the bottom
    $_SESSION['foodname'] = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
               <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-th="Product">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-2 hidden-xs"><br><img src="../images/food/<?php
        echo $row['food_img'];
?>" alt="" class="img-responsive" width="100%"/></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <h4 style="margin-left:20px;"><br><?php
        echo $row['food_name'];
?></h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-th="Price"><br>Rs. <?php
        $price = $row['price'];
        echo $price;
?></td>
                           <form action="" method="POST">
                                <td data-th="Quantity"><br>
                                    <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control text-center" value="<?php
        $fquantity = $row['food_quantity'];
        echo $fquantity;
?>" min="1" max="<?php
        echo $row['quantity'];
?>">
                                </td>
                                <td data-th="Subtotal" class="text-center"><?php
        $sub_total = ($price * $fquantity);
        echo '<br>$ ' . $sub_total;
        $total = $total + $sub_total;
?>
                               </td>
                                <td class="actions">
                                        <br><input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" value="Update Quantity" name="update">
                                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="../CRUD/delete.php?id=<?php
        echo $row['food_id'];
?>&q=<?php
        echo $fquantity;
?>">Remove Item</a>
                                </td>
                            </form>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
<?php
        $_SESSION['foodname'] = array(
            "name" => $row['food_name'],
            "price" => $row['price']
        );
    }
    print_r($_SESSION['foodname']); // PRINTING ONLY LAST VALUE
}
?>
```

As you can clearly see, the following line of code is written inside the while loop, however I can only see details about the last data item.

```
$_SESSION['foodname'] = array("name" => $row['food_name'], "price" => $row['price']);
```

Is there something which I am doing fundamentally wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the way you set the `$_SESSION` inside the loop. You are overriding each time the loop gets executed. Make them an array and that should work:

```
//-------------------▾▾
$_SESSION['foodname'][] = array(
    "name" => $row['food_name'],
    "price" => $row['price']
);
```

Please note the `[]` after `$_SESSION['foodname']`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this part of code

```
<?php
        $_SESSION['foodname'] = array(
            "name" => $row['food_name'],
            "price" => $row['price']
        );
    }
    print_r($_SESSION['foodname']); // PRINTING ONLY LAST VALUE
}
?>
```

with this one

```
<?php
        $food = array(
            "name" => $row['food_name'],
            "price" => $row['price']
        );
        array_push($_SESSION['foodname'],$food);
    }
    print_r($_SESSION['foodname']); // PRINTING ONLY LAST VALUE
}
?>
```